# Do you know of a tool to turn an XSD definition of how classes will be marshalled to XML into a class diagram (UML?)?

Tags: xml, xsd, uml, class-diagram

I've been given an XSD file that describes how objects will be marshalled into XML. The XSD is complex enough that I can't keep it all in my head while trying to write some code to parse it (with SAX). What I'd like is some sort of tool that could turn this XSD definition into a class diagram. Do you know of any?

Bonus points if it'll run under Linux (but this certainly isn't a requirement).

Answer (score 1):

[Hypermodel](http://xmlmodeling.com/hypermodel) does that. It's an eclipse plugin (read: runs in Linux, albeit in Java) that reads a schema file and produces a UML model. It has a simple viewer built in if you don't have a full modelling tool.

Alternatively, use a binding framework like JAXB and find a tool to create a class diagram from the generated classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

The XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe) from Microsoft helps to transform schema into C# classes -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx

I know I know, its C#... however, at minimum it will help you understand your schema better.

Also, I see that you mentioned Linux so here is a link to the Mono Xml -

http://www.mono-project.com/XML